# Insert data into temp table from 2 source tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 `SELECT` statements that both return 13 rows from dirrefernt tables

I would like to create 1 temporary table with 2 columns and insert the 2 result rows into the 2 columns. Is there a way to do this?

So

1 - `SELECT INPOS FROM TABLE1` returns

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,18,9,10,11,12,13

2 - `SELECT CODE FROM TABLE2` returns

CODEA,CODEB,CODEC,CODED,CODEE,CODEF,CODEG,CODEH,CODEI,CODEJ,CODEK,CODEL,CODEM

I would like my temporary table to be

1  | CODEA

---

2  | CODEB

---

3 | CODEC

---

4 | CODED

---

5 | CODEE

---

6 | CODEF

---

7 | CODEG

---

8  |   CODEH

---

9 | CODEI

---

10 | CODEJ

---

11 | CODEK

---

12 | CODEL

---

13 | CODEM

Comment: You don't have any way of JOINING the tables in your structure? By id or something?

Comment: @FilipeSilva - sadly not. If this was Oracle, I could use rownum. It is literally 2 SELECT statements that I know will both return 13 values (in the correct order) and I want to populate a new 2 column table with those values side by side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT a.impos, b.code
FROM (
  (
    SELECT impos, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY impos ASC) AS link
    FROM table1
    ) AS a INNER JOIN (
    SELECT code, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY code ASC) AS link
    FROM table2
    ) AS b ON a.link = b.link
  )
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0326e/9)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WITH T1 AS (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY INPOS) ID, INPOS FROM TABLE1
),
WITH T2 AS
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CODE) ID, CODE FROM TABLE2
),
SELECT T1.INPOS, T2.CODE
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```